# Loop through reference cursor insert into API and catch exceptions

Tags: plsql

I am not sure why I am encountering an exception error.  I am still learning PL/SQL.  I am trying to put some data into a cursor from a table.  Then loop through the cursor and insert the data into an API and catch the records that are rejected by the API's.  Can I do one loop for multiple API's?  Is there something else that I am missing?

```
            declare
            fhw UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
            wdir varchar2(100);
            wfilename varchar2(100);
            cnt number;
            aidy number;
            --
            TYPE NextGen_rec IS RECORD(
            r_pidm                  rprawrd.rprawrd_pidm%TYPE,
            r_aidy_code             rprawrd.rprawrd_aidy_code%TYPE,
            r_term_code             rpratrm.rpratrm_term_code%TYPE,
            r_fund_code             rprawrd.rprawrd_fund_code%TYPE,
            r_awst_code             rprawrd.rprawrd_awst_code%TYPE,
            r_awst_date             rprawrd.rprawrd_awst_date%TYPE,
            r_accept_amt            rprawrd.rprawrd_accept_amt%TYPE,
            r_accept_date           rprawrd.rprawrd_accept_date%TYPE,
            r_offer_amt             rprawrd.rprawrd_offer_amt%TYPE,
            r_offer_date            rprawrd.rprawrd_offer_date%TYPE,
            r_data_origin           rprawrd.rprawrd_data_origin%TYPE
            );
            --
            --
            TYPE cur1 IS REF CURSOR;
            ng cur1;
            --
            Begin
            --
            Wdir := 'UTL_TTU_ST';
            wfilename  := 'ng_errors.csv';
            fhw := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(wdir,wfilename,'w');
            select count (*) into cnt
            from ttubanr.NGAWARDLD, ttubantemp.NGAWARD
            where NGAWARD_AIDY = NGAWARDLD_AIDY;
            --       
            if cnt = 0 then
            select NGAWARD_AIDY into aidy from ttubantemp.NGAWARD
            where ROWNUM < 2;
            --insert aid year if it doesn't exist with date from 01-01-2000 as place holder.
            insert into ttubanr.NGAWARDLD
            (NGAWARDLD_AIDY, NGAWARDLD_LD)
            SELECT  replace(replace (REPLACE (NGAWARD_AIDY, 'Academic Year ',null),'20',null),'-',null), '01-JAN-2017' FROM ttubantemp.NGAWARD;
            end if;   
            --  Last date for aid year found     
            --
            for award_rec in ng_rec loop
            If cnt = 1 then
            open ng FOR
            SELECT NGAWARD_NGID,
            replace(replace (REPLACE (NGAWARD_AIDY, 'Academic Year ',null),'20',null),'-',null)NGAWARD_AIDY,
            CASE 
            WHEN NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'FALL'
            THEN SUBSTR(NGAWARD_AIDY,15,4)||80
            WHEN NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'SPRING'
            THEN SUBSTR(NGAWARD_AIDY,20,4)||10
            END NGAWARD_TERM,
            (SELECT SPRIDEN_PIDM FROM SPRIDEN WHERE SPRIDEN_ID = NGAWARD_ID AND SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL) NGAWARD_PIDM,
            NGAWARD_ID,
            NGAWARD_FUND,
            NGAWARD_AMT,
            CASE WHEN NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'ANNUAL'
                                THEN 'A'
                                WHEN NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'FALL'
                                THEN 'F'
                                WHEN NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'SPRING'
                                THEN 'S'
                                END NGAWARD_PERIOD,
            CASE WHEN NGAWARD_STATUS = 'GrantAward'
                                     THEN 'I'
                                     WHEN NGAWARD_STATUS = 'ModifyAward'
                                     THEN 'U'
                                     WHEN NGAWARD_STATUS = 'RemoveSingleSeasonAward'
                                     THEN 'C'
                                     WHEN NGAWARD_STATUS = 'RevokeRenewableAward'
                                     THEN 'C'
                                      WHEN NGAWARD_STATUS = 'DeleteAward'
                                     THEN 'C'
                                     END NGAWARD_STATUS,
            NGAWARD_ADATE
            FROM ttubantemp.NGAWARD,  ttubanr.NGAWARDLD, SPRIDEN                   
            WHERE 
            SPRIDEN_ID = NGAWARD_ID
            AND NGAWARD_AIDY = NGAWARDLD_AIDY
            and NGAWARD_ADATE > NGAWARDLD_LDATE
            AND SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
            order by NGAWARD_ID,  NGAWARD_FUND, NGAWARD_ADATE;
            fetch ng into ng_rec;
            End If;
            --
                IF ng_rec.NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'A' AND ng_rec.NGAWARD_STATUS = 'I'
                THEN  
                    rp_award.p_create(p_aidy_code  =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AIDY,
                                   p_pidm          =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_PIDM,
                                   p_fund_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_FUND,
                                   p_awst_code     =>        'A',
                                   p_awst_date     =>        sysdate,
                                   p_accept_amt    =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_accept_date   =>        sysdate,
                                   p_offer_amt     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_offer_date    =>        sysdate,
                                   p_data_origin   =>        'NextGen');
            --                              
                      gb_common.p_commit;
            --Year award Update
                ELSIF ng_rec.NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'A' AND ng_rec.NGAWARD_STATUS = 'U'
                THEN  
                    rp_award.p_update(p_aidy_code  =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AIDY,
                                   p_pidm          =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_PIDM,
                                   p_fund_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_FUND,
                                   p_awst_code     =>        'A',
                                   p_awst_date     =>        sysdate,
                                   p_accept_amt    =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_accept_date   =>        sysdate,
                                   p_offer_amt     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_data_origin   =>        'NextGen');
            --                              
                      gb_common.p_commit;        
            --Year award cancel
                ELSIF ng_rec.NGAWARD_PERIOD = 'A' AND ng_rec.NGAWARD_STATUS = 'C'
                THEN  
                    rp_award.p_update(p_aidy_code  =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AIDY,
                                   p_pidm          =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_PIDM,
                                   p_fund_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_FUND,
                                   p_awst_code     =>        'C',
                                   p_awst_date     =>        sysdate,
                                   p_data_origin   =>        'NextGen');
            --                              
                      gb_common.p_commit;
            --Term award insert
                ELSIF ng_rec.NGAWARD_PERIOD in ('F','S') AND ng_rec.NGAWARD_STATUS = 'I'
                THEN  
            rp_award_schedule.p_create(p_aidy_code  =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AIDY,
                                   p_term_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_TERM,
                                   p_pidm          =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_PIDM,
                                   p_fund_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_FUND,
                                   p_awst_code     =>        'A',
                                   p_awst_date     =>        sysdate,
                                   p_accept_amt    =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_accept_date   =>        sysdate,
                                   p_offer_amt     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_offer_date    =>        sysdate,
                                   p_data_origin   =>        'NextGen');
            --                              
                      gb_common.p_commit; 
            --Term award update
                ELSIF ng_rec.NGAWARD_PERIOD in ('F','S') AND ng_rec.NGAWARD_STATUS = 'U'
                THEN  
            rp_award_schedule.p_update(p_aidy_code  =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AIDY,
                                   p_term_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_TERM,
                                   p_pidm          =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_PIDM,
                                   p_fund_code     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_FUND,
                                   p_accept_amt    =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_offer_amt     =>        ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT,
                                   p_data_origin   =>        'NextGen');
            --                              
                      gb_common.p_commit;  
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            gb_common.p_rollback;
            IF SQLCODE = gb_event.APP_ERROR THEN
            utl_file.put_line(fhw,'Rollback renumbering '||sqlerrm||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_NGID||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_ID||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_AIDY||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_TERM||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_FUND||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_AMT||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_STATUS||','||ng_rec.NGAWARD_ADATE);           
            --
            end loop;
            --
            end if;
            --
            --CLOSE ng_rec;
            UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fhw);
            end;
```

Comment: for award_rec in ng_rec loop.... where is ng_rec cursor declaration? and please mentioned what exception you getting